# Switching the bits

Tags: c, bit-shift, bit

How can I switch the certain bits of a number? For example, given bit representation (just an example, the syntax is surely wrong!):

```
someNumber = 00110111
changeNumber = 11100110
```

Then how can I change the far right bit of `someNumber` with the far right bit of the `changeNumber` without changing the rest bits of the `someNumber`? So the result would be:

```
00110111   //someNumber
11100110   //changeNumber
________
00110110
```

Comment: Have you looked at the bit shifting operator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 3):

Extract the far right bit of `changeNumber`:

```
changeNumber & 1
```

Remove the far right bit of `someNumber`:

```
someNumber & ~1
```

And OR them together:

```
 (changeNumber & 1) | (someNumber & ~1)
```

To set bit *n*, change 1 to *2<sup>n</sup>*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following steps:

1. Clear the last bit of `someNumber`.

   ```
   someNumber &= ~1
   ```
2. Extract the last bit of `changeNumber`

   ```
   int lastBit = changeNumber & 1;
   ```
3. Set the last bit of `someNumber`:

   ```
   someNumber |= lastBit;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One a similar line as Martin,

Test the last bit of someNumber, and use the result to select the operation to change some number ('bitwise and' or 'bitwise or')

```
#DEFINE SWITCH_MASK_OR 0b00000001
#DEFINE SWITCH_MASK_AND (~SWITCH_MASK_OR)
...
result = changeNumber & SWITCH_MASK_OR ? \
         someNumber | SWITCH_MASK_OR : someNumber & SWITCH_MASK_AND;
```

Answer (score 0):

AND the changenumber with a mask of 00000001, so extracting the state of the lowest bit, all others set to 0: 00000000

AND the somenumber with a mask of 11111110, so setting the lowest bit to 0 while leaving the rest unchanged: 00110110

OR the two results together, so : 00110110